# php72-php-fpm failed to start

Tags: centos, php-fpm

I have two versions of PHP on my CentOS 7 Apache server:

- 5.6
- 7.2

It was working but now I'm getting some weird errors that I can't decipher or use to debug.

Doing:

```
$ sudo service php72-php-fpm restart
```

showed me this:

```
Job for php72-php-fpm.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered causing the control process to dump core. See "systemctl status php72-php-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Running:

```
$ systemctl status php72-php-fpm.service
```

Showed:

```
php72-php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php72-php-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Tue 2019-04-09 12:09:33 BST; 40s ago
  Process: 15205 ExecStart=/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
 Main PID: 15205 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)

Apr 09 12:09:32 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
Apr 09 12:09:32 localhost.localdomain php-fpm[15205]: [09-Apr-2019 12:09:32] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8' (tried: /opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8 (/opt/remi/php72...
Apr 09 12:09:32 localhost.localdomain php-fpm[15205]: [09-Apr-2019 12:09:32] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: /opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci (/opt/remi...
Apr 09 12:09:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: php72-php-fpm.service: main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Apr 09 12:09:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
Apr 09 12:09:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit php72-php-fpm.service entered failed state.
Apr 09 12:09:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: php72-php-fpm.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

and

```
$ journal -xe
```

Showed nothing to do with the service.

How do I go about debugging and fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From pasted error, you have installed oci8 extension without having oracle library (version 18.3).

Install the library from [Oracle site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/downloads/index.html), and fix LD_LIBRARY_PATH for FPM.

You can either

- global set linker path (will work all SAPI)

`echo /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib >>/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf`

**Or**

- Set FPM service environnement (only for FPM)

`systemctl edit php72-php-fpm`

And add a Environnement directive there

```
[Service]
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib
```

If you don't need this extension, simply remove it

```
yum remove php72-php-oci8
```

> It was working but now I'm getting some weird errors...

If updated from a previous version, build with an older client library version, you need to also update the library.

Answer (score 0):

The log you posted hinted at oracle being in the mix. It's likely that you are missing required dependencies. Double check your installed oracle packages and provide a list if this doesn't fix your problem.